# NTP service shown "inactive" with 'timedatectl status'

Tags: ntpd, systemd-timesyncd

On an Archlinux host, I noticed that command `timedatectl status` returned correct result for times (local and UTC) but also mentioned that the NTP service was inactive.

That struck me as odd because `ntpd.service` is enabled and active on that machine, even though `systemd-timesynd.service` is present but not enabled.

On https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542959/72707 I saw that provided the `systemd-timesync.service` is available, doing:

```
# timedatectl set-ntp true
```

is enough to show an active NTP service in the output of `timedatectl status`.

I also saw that it automatically enabled and activated `systemd-timesync.service`.

Hence my question:
Do I need the `ntpd.service` at all ? Is there a differentiated need for both `systemd-timesync.service` and `ntpd.service`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from @don_crissti's comment to directly answer OP's query:

> You don't need the ntpd.service if you're using the timesyncd one. I use the latter on several desktops that don't even have the ntp package installed. Read the arch wiki entry about it here: wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-timesyncd

Aside from that quote, with modern versions of `timedatectl` (and corresponding `systemd-timedated`), there is a list of time synchronization services in `/usr/lib/systemd/ntp-units.d/*.list` files. As usual, you can use `/usr/local/lib/systemd/ntp-units.d/*.list` files to make `timedatectl` aware of locally-administered (= not installed from packages) time synchronization services, or `/etc/systemd/ntp-units.d/*.list` for administrative overrides to existing time sync service lists.

Setting the environment variable `SYSTEMD_TIMEDATED_NTP_SERVICES` for the `systemd-timedated` service is another way you can override the list of time sync services.

When you do a `timedatectl set-ntp true`, `systemd-timedated` will look at its list of time synchronization service names, and will start the first listed service that is actually available.

To make your `timedatectl` aware of `ntpd.service`, you could do something like this:

```
echo "ntpd.service" | sudo tee /etc/systemd/ntp-units.d/10-ntpd.list
```

`systemd-timesyncd` was originally developed as a minimalistic service to just periodically fetch time from a NTP server, effectively a SNTP client. It seems to be developing into a more complete NTP client, but I'm unsure as to how it compares to e.g. classic `ntpd` at this time.

A more full-featured NTP synchronization service like `chronyd` or `ntpd` will also constantly measure packet round-trip times between the local system and the NTP time sources, compensate for it, and also measure and compensate for systematic errors of the local system clock.

`systemd-timesyncd` was originally meant for embedded systems and other use cases where it's nice to have "human-scale" correct time, but not necessary to achieve very high accuracy.

With a well-configured `chronyd` or `ntpd` and a good set of nearby NTP servers, you can get your systems synchronized to within a millisecond or better.

If you need your systems synchronized down to the microsecond or even better, you can get with NTP with careful tweaking, but it might be better to use PTP in that case.

Note that the development of the classic `ntpd` has stalled in the recent year or two, and it has some known security issues. Newer implementations like `chronyd` and [NTPsec](https://ntpsec.org/) might be more secure.

Comment: +1: Truly informative contribution  although i had read on the dfference between `ntp` and `ntpd` already ans well as on the comparatively lightweight character of `systemd-timesyncd`. I do not accept your answer because it does not apply to OP. If with @don_crissti's approval you include their comment in your answer, i will make sure i accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @don_crissti: in the absence of an answer by telcoM, I integrated your answer in his/hers and accepted the result as the official answer. Thank you both.